# Double Integration?

Tags: integration

I'm having trouble integrating this function.

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \int_{0}^{1}
 \frac{y\ln(1-x^2-y^2)}{x-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \,dy\, dx$$

I just need to double integrate over the domain but when I first integrate with $dy$ it seems wrong.  When I integrate this I get an extremely long answer, can anyone help me with this?

Comment: The integrand has a singularity along the unit circle in the domain; why should the integral even exist?

Comment: @GregMartin i noticed this as well however, Im still trying to integrate it and its quite difficult

Comment: The worse singularity is the fact that the integrand looks like $$-\frac{2x}y\ln(1-x^2)$$ near the $x$-axis, and that is unrecoverable. Go back to where you got the problem from and try to find out if you are doing anything wrong.

Comment: @someguy Where did you encounter this integral? The unusual bounds of integration in your problem make me all but certain that the problem was misstated.

Comment: Split off a quarter circle of radius $\pi/4$ from the integral and observe  $$\int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{\pi/4} \frac{\rho \sin(\phi)\log(1-\rho^2)}{\cos(\phi)-1}\,d\rho\,d\phi=- \int_0^{\pi/2} \cot(\phi/2) \int_0^{\pi/4} \rho \log(1-\rho^2)\,d\rho\,d\phi$$which clearly diverges due to the singularity at $\phi=0$.